# Physical setup for collecting tod_training data?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder how to collect tod_training data? From a [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/355/recording-a-tod_training-bag) I know that we should be able use

```
roslaunch tod_training record_openni.launch bag:=pwd/awesome.bag interval:=0.5
```

Unfortunately, the tutorial about recording a training bag is empty. I wonder how to setup our environment. We need fiducial markers rigidly attached to a rotating table and in between these markers, we place an object, correct? Is it enough to create a setup as shown on the picture?

[image: image description]

(*image showing part of the sample training bags found in the base-creation tutorial*)

- Must the print size of the fiducial markers have a certain size?
- Are there any crucial aspects I have to be aware of in my preparation?

As collection of training data can be time-consuming and needs hardware, I want to make sure we're on the right track before starting the attempt.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9536/physical-setup-for-collecting-tod_training-data?/) by [Julius](https://answers.ros.org/users/252/julius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 960 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> > We need fiducial markers rigidly attached to a rotating table and in between these markers, we place an object, correct?

Yes.

> > Is it enough to create a setup as shown on the picture?

Yes.

> > Must the print size of the fiducial markers have a certain size?

No. You can use different markers (different cells count, size, etc). But you should change fiducial configuration file (fiducial.yaml) for your markers.

> > Are there any crucial aspects I have to be aware of in my preparation?

I think no. You should only write bag file with object rotation.

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2011-04-04**:
Alexander, our understanding is that ./bin/fiducial program in pkg fiducial generates that fiducial.yaml file. However, the question is how do we get in the description of 2 checkerboards as done in the following file: http://vault.willowgarage.com/wgdata1/vol1/tod_kinect_bags/training/fiducial.yml?